# Dynamic binding in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

Basically I am looking for shorthand version of this:

```
<div class="">
{{listObject.firstHeaderKey.type === 'value' ? listObject.firstHeaderKey.key: item[listObject.firstHeaderKey.key}}
</div>
```

My data could either be a string or an expression i.e.

```
<div *ngFor="let mix of mixList">
    <div>
    {{mix}}
    </div>
</div>
```

mix can either be " 'text' " or "obj[text]" and accordingly the template should evaluate.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be other solution (atleast to me) looking at the heterogeneous content of your list. Better make your list homogeneous, restructure it so that `obj[text]` works for all `mix` values.

Answer (score 2):

According to best practisies you should do this in your typescript file

```
mix: any;
this.mix === 'value' ? listObject.firstHeaderKey.key : 
                       item[listObject.firstHeaderKey.key]
```

And template should be something like this:

```
<div>
{{mix}}
</div>
```

Comment: Basically the content is inside a list (ngFor) and in that case I would have to call a function for every single displaying which is not optimal way